# How did Saul find Walt?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

This moment from S2E8 ("Better Call Saul") has been nagging me for a while. Saul enters Walt's classroom:

> **Walt:** How did you find me?
>
> **Saul:** We should talk about that. It should be much, much harder for people to track you down. My PI charged me for three hours, so I seriously doubt it took him more than one.

As we later find out, Saul's PI is Mike. *But how did Mike find Walt?* Keep in mind that at this point, Saul still thinks Walt is Badger's uncle; their only interactions have been those connected with Badger's arrest.

In addition, neither Gus nor Mike has made any appearance in the show yet.

Any ideas? I remember being a little curious when watching this as to how Saul could have found Walt; to me, at least, he seemed to have covered his tracks sufficiently.

Comment: With nothing to back this up, I would expect Mike used contacts of his to find a middle aged white guy with a chemistry background. Then, staked out a few of the more promising ones, and then found a match for the description. And its a show, so that's just how they explained Saul finding him. It may not be more than that.

Comment: @Levi: I was thinking of that — that they don't *have* to have a good explanation because its fiction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no exact story behind how Mike found Walt. We can make hunches about how Mike could have tracked Walt. Saul knew what this guy looked like. Saul knew that this guy had some health issue (remember Walt's coughing). He would have passed on this information to Mike and Mike being an ex cop must have been faimiliar with these kind of investigations. We can also assume that Mike must have had a good network within the town. Also Mike is portrayed as a very smart and clean guy in the series so once he has a face and a little more information it would not have been too difficult for him to track him down. Also please note that these are very minor sub plots and it would not have been possible to explain each and every thing in detail. We can assume somthings from character's skills and abilities.

Comment: AMC recently posted this: http://www.amctv.com/shows/better-call-saul/client-development-comic. A plausible explanation.

Comment: @baum The link has changed to http://www.amc.com/shows/better-call-saul/exclusives/client-development-comic, but that's a great explanation!

Answer (score -1):

Saul told Jesse and walt to give him a dollar so maybe he gave the dollar to mike to reveal the fingerprints and found them. 
Ok that took place when Jessy and Walt kidnapped Saul in Season 2 Episode 8 and after they negotiate, Saul told them "First Thing ,you'll put a dollar in my pocket,both of you."

Comment: Which episode did this take place in?

Comment: I like this theory! Not sure if I believe it, but it made me smile. :)

Comment: That's a very interesting theory, please [edit] your answer to add in which episode that happens.